# biblatex: Setting maxnames on individual entries

Tags: biblatex, biber, author-number

I'm using `biblatex` (with biber as backend). I use the global `maxnames` option to shorten author lists (with "et al."). However, I would like to create some exceptions to this rule for some specific entries.

I was hoping I could use the `options` entry field (for per-entry options).

For example, I would use the following global setting:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric-comp,citestyle=numeric-comp,backend=biber,maxnames=3]{biblatex}
```

I would then override the `maxnames` setting for some individual items, for example to allow a longer authors list, like so:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Vallejos2009b,
  author = {John Doe and Pete Peters and Jane Jones and John Johnson and Alison Anderson},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {...},
  year = {2009},
  options = {maxnames=5}
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work because `maxnames` is not supported as an entry-level option. At least in the current biblatex version.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do something like that?

PS: I use numeric citation style so my question only concerns the abbreviation of author lists in the bibliography itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't reliably do this yourself by either bib file keywords or style edits because maxnames (and maxbibnames, maxalphanames) is used internally by biber to do all sorts of things when generating the .bbl. So if it's not supported in biber as a per-entry option, entry information will potentially be wrong/inconsistent like labels, hashes and uniquename/uniquelist settings.

We have had a look at this and the functionality will be implemented in the next biber and biblatex versions, probably 0.9.6/1.7. You will be able to set:

maxnames/minnames
maxcitenames/mincitenames
maxbibnames/minbibnames
maxalphanames/minalphanames
maxitems/minitems

on a per-type and per-entry basis.

Just to confirm that this is now implemented in biber 0.9.6/biblatex 1.7 which were released a couple of days ago.

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it's ok.

Comment: +1 I can see how this would be a concern for disambiguation. Marco's current solution resets `maxnames` locally and only before printing each bibliography entry. So aside from that concern, would this approach not be reasonable?

Comment: Of course, I didn't mean to cast aspersions. biber is a bit of a black box to most people because it's assumed mostly that it just does what bibtex does for biblatex but with Unicode. In fact, it does an enormous amount more than that and is quite complex internally - I have added some diagrams and comments to the biber PDF documentation recently on this topic. biber does all of the processing of uniqueness information, hashes, label generation etc. - this is all tied up with settings like max/minnames so the solution may work but you may see odd things happening without direct support

Comment: OK. Good to know. I'll be the first to admit I am completely ignorant as to how biber works. It's high time I take a look at that documentation. Thanks!

Comment: New doc is here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/0.9.5/documentation/biber.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your feedback PLK. I just opened a feature request: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3403810&group_id=244752&atid=1126006

Comment: However, I think it was requested before and rejected (see my comment on sourceforge). Anyway, maybe this can be reconsidered.

Comment: I commented on it - that old request was pre-biber and so it was at the time impossible I think. Should be possible now (certainly possible in biber) but it's up to the biblatex maintainer in the end.

Comment: Making max/min* options per-entry would also automatically make them per-type too which is a nice bonus

Comment: I edited my reply to confirm that this is planned for the next biber/biblatex release.

Comment: @PLK As this is now released, perhaps you might revise your answer to state that this did not used to be possible but that it is now, and give an example of the new approach?

Answer (score 10):

The solution is a *HACK*. See the legitimate answer of PLK.

You must modify each bibitem. I would to this by setting a special `keyword` to the relevant bib entry. At the beginning of the bibitem you can test whether the key is set or not. If the key is set  you can change the counter `maxnames`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Vallejos2009b,
  author = {John Doe and Pete Peters and Jane Jones and John Johnson and Alison Anderson},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {...},
  year = {2009},
  keywords={increasemaxnames},
}

@book{test,
author="John Smith and John Doe and Pete Peters and Jane Jones and John Johnson",
title="TITLE",
year=2009,
publisher="PUP",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric-comp,citestyle=numeric-comp,backend=biber,maxnames=3]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifkeyword{increasemaxnames}%
   {\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}
   {\setcounter{maxnames}{3}}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{Vallejos2009b} \cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Audrey wishes I method without editing the bib file. This is possible with a comparison of the `entrykey`. I build a command named `\individualentry`. The command needs a comma separate list of `entrykeys`. If the `entrykey` doesn't exist it will works too ;-)

Here the definition of the command:

```
\newrobustcmd*\individualentry[1]{%
  \def\tempa{}%
  \def\tempb{ ( test {\ifstrequal{2}{1}} ) }%
  \forcsvlist{\listeadd\tempa}{#1}
  \def\do##1{%
     \gappto\tempb{ or (test  {\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{##1}}) }
  }%
  \dolistloop{\tempa}%
  \AtEveryBibitem{
    \expandafter\ifboolexpr\expandafter{\tempb}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{3}}
  }
}
```

It is important that the command is used in the preamble!

Here the whole example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Vallejos2009b,
  author = {John Doe and Pete Peters and Jane Jones and John Johnson and Alison Anderson},
  title = {Some Title},
  booktitle = {...},
  year = {2009},
  keywords={increasemaxnames},
}

@book{test,
author="John Smith and John Doe and Pete Peters and Jane Jones and John Johnson",
title="TITLE",
year=2009,
publisher="PUP",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric-comp,citestyle=numeric-comp,backend=biber,maxnames=3]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\newrobustcmd*\individualentry[1]{%
  \def\tempa{}%
  \def\tempb{ ( test {\ifstrequal{2}{1}} ) }%
  \forcsvlist{\listeadd\tempa}{#1}%
  \def\do##1{%
     \gappto\tempb{ or (test  {\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{##1}}) }%
  }%
  \dolistloop{\tempa}%
  \AtEveryBibitem{%
    \expandafter\ifboolexpr\expandafter{\tempb}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{3}}%
  }%%
  \AtEveryCitekey{%
     \expandafter\ifboolexpr\expandafter{\tempb}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}%
            {\setcounter{maxnames}{3}}%
  }%
}
%\individualentry{foo,Vallejos2009b,test}
\individualentry{foo,Vallejos2009b}
\begin{document}
\cite{Vallejos2009b} \cite{test} 

\fullcite{Vallejos2009b}

 \fullcite{test} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 You can avoid `bib` file edits by using the test `\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{Vallejos2009b}{\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}{}` in `\AtEveryBibitem`.

Comment: @Audrey: This was my first idea. But than I must do it for every `entrykey`. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah. It's just a matter of preference. I'd be too lazy to edit the `bib` file. Expanding the test to multiple keys using something like `\ifboolexpr` would seem like less work to me, especially if my `bib` file contains many entries.

Comment: Thanks Marco, this is great. However, I did notice it only affects the actual bibliography and not the results of `\fullcite{Vallejos2009b}`. Is there a way to let it affect fullcite as well? Or an alternative to fullcite which would be affected?

Comment: @Matthias: You wishes only the bibliography. Now also the cite-command?

Comment: @Audrey: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Marco: I should have been more clear from the beginning. In my PS I meant that I didn't need `maxnames` customisations for the citations (because I use numeric citation, so there is no [JohnsonEtAl2009] or something, only [5] for example). However, I do use `\fullcite` sometimes, this produces a fully formatted bibliography entry anywhere in the document text (so outside the bibliography listing). Because the result of `\fullcite` is more or less the same as in the bibliography I was hoping the `maxnames` hack would also affect `\fullcite`, but it does not.

Comment: @Matthias: You can use the *HACK* in the same way with `AtEveryCitekey`. I will expand my second example. I think you can adapt it to the first one.

Comment: @Marco I didn't mean to imply I was insisting on an edit, although I do like that new command. `\ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{<key1>}} or test {\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{<key2>}} }{\setcounter{maxnames}{5}}{}` was the less fancy test I had in mind.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks, the combination of `AtEveryBibitem` and `AtEveryCitekey` produces the result I wanted and so far I haven't spotted any side effects.