# Biblatex mincitenames not respected with authoryear

Tags: biblatex, author-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex)

I am using biblatex to manage the bibliography of a large document.
Everything is working fine, but I have found a small problem that I am not able to solve:

I am calling:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxbibnames=99, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, backref=true, hyperref=true, dashed=false, firstinits=true, backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
```

At the beginning of my document, and everything works as expected, viz.

> \textcite{me2012}  ->  me (2012)
>
> \textcite{me_and_you2012}  ->  me and you (2012)
>
> \textcite{me_and_fred_and_dave2012}  ->  me et al. (2012)

However if I have another "me et al." in the document, the following thing happens:

> \textcite{me_and_fred_and_dave2012}  ->  me, fred, et al. (2012)
>
> \textcite{me_and_sarah_and_lucy2012}  ->  me, sarah,  et al. (2012)

This is very annoying since it seems to be ignoring the mincitenames=1 given at the beginning. I was expecting:

> \textcite{me_and_fred_and_dave2012}  ->  me et al. (2012)
>
> \textcite{me_and_sarah_and_lucy2012}  ->  me et al. (2012)

Is there any way to block this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry if this was a duplicate, I looked on the internet before posting and didn't really find anything until I turned up the vaguely related post I replied with!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on an answer from [These guys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48846/biblatex-et-al-beginning-from-second-citation), I have managed to work out that this behaviour is achieved by changing the \usepackage in the preamble to:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxbibnames=99, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, backref=true, hyperref=true, dashed=false, firstinits=true, backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

i.e., by adding `uniquename=false, uniquelist=false` to the list of options!

Comment: Great that you solved it, and thanks for sharing your findings. Remember that it's ok to accept your own answer, it'll help future readers know the correct answer.

Comment: Incidentally, if you use `citestyle=apa`, this breaks completely. Moral of the story? Always use `citestyle=authoryear`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was citing two articles with more than ten authors each, but for which the first ten authors were identical and in the same order, which produced the following atrocity: "bla bla (Rendu, Beauval, Crevecoeur, Bayle, Balzeau, Bismuth, Bourguignon, Delfour, Faivre, Lacrampe-Cuyaubère, et al., 2014; Rendu, Beauval, Crevecoeur, Bayle, Balzeau, Bismuth, Bourguignon, Delfour, Faivre, Lacrampe-Cuyaubère, et al., 2016)"