# How to cite first and (maximum) second author and year?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Goodmorning everyone.

In my thesis I need to cite authors with the following rules,but with the citation style authoryear it doesn't work (I'm using biblatex):

- Author et al. year - if there is more than two authors
- Author and coauthor year - if there are two authors
- Author et al. year a - if there is more than a pubblication with the same author

**An example**:

This is my database:

```
@article{sism,
    author = {Mantovani, E.  and Tamburelli, C. and Babbucci, D. and Viti, M. and Cenni, N.},
    date = {2020},
}
@article{geodin,
    author = {Mantovani, E. and Viti, M. and Babbucci, D. and Tamburelli, C. and Cenni, N.},
    date = {2020},
}
@article{mant14,
    author = {Mantovani, E.  and Viti, M. and Babbucci, D. and Tamburelli, C. and Cenni, N. and Baglione, M. and D'Intinosante, V.},
    date = {2014},
}

@article{savage70,
    author = {Savage, J. C. and Burford, R. O.},
    date = {1970},
}
```

If I cite `\cite{sism}` it shows *Mantovani, Tamburelli et al. 2020* instead of *Mantovani et al. 2020a*

If I cite `\cite{geodin}` it shows *Mantovani, Viti, Babbucci, Tamburelli and Cenni 2020* instead of *Mantovani et al. 2020b*

If I cite `\cite{mant14}` it shows *Mantovani, Viti, Babbucci, Tamburelli, Cenni, Baglione and D'Intinosante 2014* instead of *Mantovani et al. 2014*

If I cite `\cite{savage70}` it shows *Savage and Burford 1970* and it's ok.

I tried to set `maxcitenames=1` but doing so if I `\cite{savage70}` it shows *Savage et. al 1970* instead of *Savage and Burford 1970*.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: with maxcitename the three first long citations don't change, don't know why.

Comment: `maxcitenames=2`?

Comment: Doing so, the outputs would be:

*Mantovani, Tamburelli et al. 2020*

*Mantovani, Viti, Babbucci, Tamburelli and Cenni 2020*

*Mantovani, Viti, Babbucci, Tamburelli, Cenni, Baglione and D'Intinosante 2014 *

*Savage and Burford 1970*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both `maxnames` and `minnames`:

I quote from the manual:

> maxnames=〈integer〉default:3 A threshold affecting all lists of names
> (author,editor, etc.). If a list exceeds thisthreshold, i. e., if it
> holds more than〈integer〉names, it is automatically truncated according
> to the setting of theminnamesoption.maxnamesis the master optionwhich
> setsmaxbibnames,maxcitenamesandmaxsortnames. Note that the uniquelist
> feature can locally override maxnames, see the documentation of the
> uniquelist option in §3.1.2.3and §4.11.4.

> minnames=〈integer〉default:1 A limit affecting all lists of names
> (author,editor, etc.). If a list holds morethan〈maxnames〉names, it is
> automatically truncated to〈minnames〉names. The〈minnames〉value must be
> smaller than or equal to〈maxnames. minnamesisthe master option which
> sets both minbibnames and mincitenames. Like maxnames the value of
> minnames can be overridden by uniquelist.

The letter in the citation can be produced using the sortyear variable (cf. also this question: [Biblatex mincitenames not respected with authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84481/118712) )

The following code should produce the output you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
    @article{sism,
        author = {Mantovani, E.  and Tamburelli, C. and Babbucci, D. and Viti, M. and Cenni, N.},
        year = {2020},
        sortyear={2020-1},
    }
    @article{geodin,
        author = {Mantovani, E. and Viti, M. and Babbucci, D. and Tamburelli, C. and Cenni, N.},
        year = {2020},
        sortyear={2020-2},
    }
    @article{mant14,
        author = {Mantovani, E.  and Viti, M. and Babbucci, D. and Tamburelli, C. and Cenni, N. and Baglione, M. and D'Intinosante, V.},
        year = {2014},
    }
    
    @article{savage70,
        author = {Savage, J. C. and Burford, R. O.},
        year = {1970},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,maxnames=2,minnames=1,uniquelist=true,uniquename=true,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}
    \cite{sism} \cite{geodin} \cite{mant14} \cite{savage70}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Note that using `authoryear-comp` or `authoryear` with this setting results in ambiguous references, as only the first author is given and the letter differentiating the two entries is not part of the reference list. I recomment setting `minnames` to an appropriate number to reflect that. (In your case, that would be `2`)

Comment: The letters are also added to the year even without `sortyear`. `sortyear` can only influence which work gets which letter. It may make the answer even more helpful to mention more explicitly that `maxnames` and `minnames` on their own are often not enough to get the desired effect, you also need `uniquelist` (and possibly also `uniquename`). The options are used in the code, but making that more explicit may help users to understand better what is going on.