# output does not contain 'et al.', although the citation abbreviates to one author

Tags: biblatex, natbib, author-number

i have found many helpful answers to other question here, so i hope you can solve my problems as well. I'm currently writing my masters thesis and had to change to using biblatex, which brought a lot of problems along.

For me it looked like the solutions in [biblatex – et al. beginning from second citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48846/biblatex-et-al-beginning-from-second-citation) would shorten several authors down to et al. after the second name, but it doesn't. I do always only get the first author and the year without the "et al."

I could only find other questions around here on changing the et al. into different languages or symbols, but not on creating it!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp, 
bibstyle= authoryear,
citetracker=true,
maxnames=99,
maxcitenames=2,
sorting=nyt,
uniquelist=false,
natbib=true,
useprefix=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}\clearfield{namehash}}}%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}%
%
\let\oldmultinamedelim\multinamedelim %altes Trennzeichen speichern
\let\oldfinalnamedelim\finalnamedelim %altes Trennzeichen speichern
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~,\space} %
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~\&\space} %

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\oldmultinamedelim}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\oldfinalnamedelim}%
}



\begin{document}\selectlanguage{english}

The study of \textcite[][]{Behr} \\
They say \textcite[][]{Behr} \\
..substantial lack of understanding" \parencite[][]{Behr}


\printbibliography[title={References}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}\label{sec:ref}

\end{document}
```

with the article for literatur.bib:

```
@article{Behr,
 author ={Behr, M. and Wachsmuth, I. and Post, T. and Lesh, R.},
title ={Order and {E}quivalence of {R}ational {N}umbers: {A} {C}linical {T}eaching {E}xperiment},
 journal ={Journal for {R}esearch in {M}athematics {E}ducation},
volume ={15},
 year ={1984},
 pages ={323--341}
}
```

What comes out is:
[image: resulting text]
And as i just noticed there is another mistake:
Why does it put spaces bevor the commas, isn't the ~ ment to prevent this?
-> This was solved by deleting the ~.

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: Did you try the parameters `maxnames=1, minnames=1` in your options of biblatex package?

Comment: `~` is an unbreakable space. And I get Behr et al. in the citations. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: I tried max- and minnames=1, but it didn't change anything and i updated all my systems about 2 weeks ago - so they should be fine i guess.

Comment: I also get the correct output from this example. I don't know if there has been an earlier bug affecting this, but maybe, and an updated system could still have an oldish TeX installation.

Comment: So do I understand you right: Delete TeX and install allover again?

Comment: I don't think anyone has suggested that. What kind of TeX installation do you have?

Comment: I'm not quite sure: MikTex 2.9 and WinShell editor - is there more you need to know?

Comment: You should use something like `\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace} %
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\addspace} %` to format the delimiters. To your real problem: What do your latex-log `.log` and your biber-log `.blg` say? Also try to delete the biber-cache. You get the directory, if you run `biber --cache` on your console. Then delete that directory.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no clue where to find the .blg file (I do only have a .bbl)? The log file doesn't have any errors or warnings in it.
Deleting the directory didn't solve anything.

Comment: Doy ou get any error messages/warnings if you run Biber on your file? After a more or less successful Biber run, there should be a `.blg` file in the working directory.

Comment: at that time there were no errors in any file.
but since that day there have been more and more problems, onto the file wasn't even compiled any more (took over 45 minutes, so i stopped the process twice).

Comment: ...
There were no errors at any time, so i figured out some of the updates i did the last days had gone wrong - i deleted miktex and installed everything again.
The original problem of the "et al." is know solved - new installation miktex 2.9 with texmaker works as it should ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved by updating to a recent version of the software (see comment above).