# biblatex verbose style full author list on first use

Tags: biblatex

When using the verbose citation style in biblatex, is there a way to have the first occurrence use the full author list and the subsequent abbreviated author lists use et al.? That is, for the first citation maxcitenames is not enforced or set to a large number.

Comment: [biblatex – et al. beginning from second citation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48846/biblatex-et-al-beginning-from-second-citation)

Comment: This has some potential. However if you use something like \citeauthor in the body of a paragraph before citing the reference in a footnote, it has already seen the citation. Therefore the footnote is abbreviated.

Comment: You could use `\citereset`. By default `\citeauthor` should not interfere with the cite trackers, so you should not get an abbreviated citation in the case you describe. Could you come up with an MWE?

Comment: My mistake, the proposed solution does work. I did find that if you include a bibliography you also need to add maxbibnames=99 (or similar) to force full listings there.