# BibLatex - First Citation all names, after that "et.al."

Tags: biblatex, citing

this is another one of these "my-thesis-has-weird-restrictions-on-citations" posts. I use biblatex-chicago.

So in my case, I have the following rules:

1. When there are 1 or 2 authors, always name both with "and" or "&"
2. When there are 3 to 6 authors, in the first citation name all of them, after that only the first with "et. al."
3. When there are more than 6 authors, only name the first with "et. al." but name all of them in the bibliography

So 1. is no big problem, because biblatex does it on its own with the argument `authordate`. The third I solve with the arguments `mincitenames=1` and `maxcitenames=6`

So right now it looks like this in my preamble. But I´m stuck on the second one. Any ideas how I can solve that without diving to deep in the code of biblatex?

```
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, uniquename=false, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=6]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Comment: https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/aer/submissions/accepted-articles/styleguide has "LaTeX authors should refer to [....]: http://www.aeaweb.org/templates/latex_templates.zip for the LaTeX template (tex)." and later "LaTeX [...] users, please use the `aea.bst` file provided in the template package." So I suggest you ditch `biblatex` in favour of the journal template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As Alan Munn commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478750/biblatex-first-citation-all-names-after-that-et-al#comment1209230_478750), the desired number of names in citations you describe seem to follow APA rules. If the rest of your style is also APA (or very APA-like), you may want to think about using `biblatex-apa`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{nussbaum,sigfridsson,companion,aksin}

\cite{nussbaum,sigfridsson,companion,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın et al., 2006; Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin, 1994; Nussbaum, 1978; Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998//Aksın et al., 2006; Goossens et al., 1994; Nussbaum, 1978; Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998]

---

You can try to emulate a similar cite name scheme by setting `maxcitenames=2` and changing the value of the `maxnames` counter locally to `6` for the first citation (as tracked by `\ifciteseen` and `citetracker`). That should work for both `biblatex-chicago` and the standard styles.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, backend=biber, citetracker]{biblatex}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, uniquename=false, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, citetracker]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{nussbaum,sigfridsson,companion,aksin}

\cite{nussbaum,sigfridsson,companion,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nussbaum 1978; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994; Aksın et al. 2006//Nussbaum 1978; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Goossens et al. 1994; Aksın et al. 2006]

See also [@Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48857/35864) to [biblatex – et al. beginning from second citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/35864) and   [@samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323481/35864) to [How to get et al. beginning with the 2nd citation with biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323478/35864). [biblatex - et. al for specific cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354623/35864) might also be relevant.

---

That all said, you mention the *American Economics Review* in the comments and a short google search leads to https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/aer/submissions/accepted-articles/styleguide which suggests

> LaTeX authors should refer to either: http://www.aeaweb.org/templates/latex_templates.zip for the LaTeX template (tex). Or, if you wish to have the ability to collaborate with Scientific Word authors, please use: http://www.aeaweb.org/templates/latex_sw-supported.templates.zip Please be sure to include the `.aux` file and `.bbl` if available.

and later

> LaTeX and Scientific Word users, please use the `aea.bst` file provided in the template package.