# How do you change how a single citation is displayed?

Tags: biblatex, lyx, authoryear

I am using biblatex in Lyx and have set the options maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99, with style=authoryear in the preamble. This has the effect of making all citations with more than 2 authors display as "Author 1 et al. (year)" in the text but list all authors in the bibliography, which IS what I want for all citations except one, where I would like to list out all three authors in the format "Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3 (year)". Is there a way to manually change the way a single citation is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `maxcitenames` on a per-entry level in the `options` field in your `.bib` file. This will then override the relevant global setting locally for that entry.

Compare `elk` (three authors and `options = {maxcitenames=3},`) to `companion` (three authors and no local `maxcitenames` setting) in the following example

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Banne Welk and Hanne Selk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  options   = {maxcitenames=3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{elk}
ipsum \textcite{companion}
dolor \textcite{aksin}
sit \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Elk, Welk, and Selk (1972) ipsum Goossens et al. (1994) dolor Aksın et al. (2006) sit Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)]

Comment: Thanks! This is almost, but not quite, what I'm looking for. To clarify, I just want to list all authors the first time I cite this reference. For instance, on the first page, I'd like to cite the reference as "Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3 (year)", but on the second page, I'd like to cite it as "Author 1 et al. (year)". Is this possible?

Comment: @user291055 Do you want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/35864?