# Command to cite only first author in biblatex authoryear

Tags: biblatex

I want to define a command `\shorttextcite` that does only print the first author and "et.al.".

The standard behavoir of `\textcite` in `authoryear` should *not* be altered.

Example and MWE:

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{john1980,
        author  = {M. John},
        title   = {A new view on the wheel},
        journal = {Proceedings in Transportation},
        year    = {1980},
    }
    @Article{john1981,
        author  = {M. John and J. Mary},
        title   = {A new view on the wheel II},
        journal = {Proceedings in Transportation},
        year    = {1981},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \textcite{john1980,john1981}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]
The `\shorttextcite` should output "John et. al. (1980,1981)" but `\textcite` should still do the same as it does now.

Comment: Mhhh, interesting question. The obvious problem from `biblatex`'s point of view is that `john1980` was not written by John et al. - it was only John, so lumping the two papers together even though the authors are different is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that oversight out! In the case I actually need to do this, all papers have more than one author.

Comment: Of course this would generally be "unsafe", as you noticed.

Comment: But I assume they have a different list of co-authors, right?

Comment: Yes, the co-authors differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a copy of `\textcite` with a little trickery to only compare the first name instead of the entire name list to check if we compress citations.

Normally we can just use the field `namehash` to compare the name lists (indeed this is what `\textcite` normally does), but `namehash` obeys the truncation settings and considers all names that are displayed in a citation. We only focus on the very first author, so we need a way to access their `hash`. This `hash` is only available if the name is processed, so we use the trick from [biblatex: filter out publications from a specific author in the references dynamically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28509/35864) and employ indexing commands. Indexing commands allow us to process a name list without printing anything.

For each first author of a work we extract his hash as well as the information whether he worked alone or "et al.". This information is saved and compared to the last citation. If the last citation has the same status they are compressed.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{john1980,
        author  = {M. John and B. Fairy},
        title   = {A new view on the wheel},
        journal = {Proceedings in Transportation},
        year    = {1980},
    }
    @Article{john1981,
        author  = {M. John and J. Mary},
        title   = {A new view on the wheel II},
        journal = {Proceedings in Transportation},
        year    = {1981},
    }
    @Article{john1982,
        author  = {M. John},
        title   = {A new view on the wheel III},
        journal = {Proceedings in Transportation},
        year    = {1983},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{cbx@chr@getfirstauthorhash}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\savefield{hash}{\cbx@thishash}%
     \ifmorenames
       {\gappto{\cbx@thishash}{@alone}}
       {\gappto{\cbx@thishash}{@etal}}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{shorttextcite}{%
  \indexnames[cbx@chr@getfirstauthorhash][1-1]{labelname}%
  \ifdefequal{\cbx@thishash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames[labelname][1-1]{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \global\let\cbx@lasthash\cbx@thishash}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@shorttextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \global\undef\cbx@thishash}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{shorttextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\shorttextcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@shorttextcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \global\undef\cbx@thishash}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \indexnames[cbx@chr@getfirstauthorhash][1-1]{labelname}%
   \ifdefequal{\cbx@thishash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \global\let\cbx@lasthash\cbx@thishash}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \shorttextcite{john1980,john1981}

  \shorttextcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

  \shorttextcite{john1982,john1981}

  \shorttextcite{john1982,john1981,john1980}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mind-boggling...

Comment: @Christoph90 I have slightly edited the solution. It should now also be able to deal with "John" and "John et al."

Comment: @moewe, why would a local set of `maxnames=1` or `blx@maxcitenames` with a hook `\AtNextCite` not work? (I suppose it is to keep pre and postnote, but given the complexity of the changes needed for textcite, wouldn't it be worth it to literally use the hook when a short citation is needed, or define a hook like `\nextshort` and use `\nextshort\textcite`?)

Comment: @gusbrs You can try with `\newrobustcmd*{\citeshortsecond}{%
  \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}}%
  \textcite}` in the example above. It does not quite work because `\textcite` uses `namehash` to compare the name lists (and to decide whether or not to 'compactify' the citations), but `namehash` is computed by Biber based on the global `max(cite)names` settings and does not respond dynamically to setting `maxnames=1`. This is basically what PLK explains in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27359/35864

Comment: @moewe Ah, it's the `-comp` variant! Indeed that complicates things. Thanks for clearing it up!